# Device ID in Flutter: device_info_plus package returns null when requesting androidId

Tags: flutter, dart, deviceid

I'm a new Flutter developer, I'm about to develop a Flutter app which needs to use device id so I decided to use the `device_info_plus` package to get `androidId`, but when I request device info in order to get `androidId` within it, it returns `null` and also does not even exist in `toMap()` object. I don't know exactly what happened but all the documentation I went through says that this package could give me the device id.

Here is the function

```
Future<Object?> getId() async {
    var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    if (Platform.isIOS) { // import 'dart:io'
      var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      return iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // unique ID on iOS
    } else if(Platform.isAndroid) {
      var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      print(androidDeviceInfo.androidId);
      return androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // unique ID on Android
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`androidId` functionality was removed from version 4.0.0.
You can see it from the Changelog [here](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/changelog).

If you'd like to get `androidId`, you need to downgrade device_info_plus in pubspec.yaml

`device_info_plus: 3.2.4`

P.S. There is [the issue](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/972) on Github that you can upvote. Probably this functionality will be returned.

Comment: It's weird how the Changelog says it's removed when it reality they just forced that getter to just... always return `null`. Furthermore, this is not documented. Not a good piece of work there.

Comment: It's not documented nor deprecated*. Which is even worse

Comment: The change log states that it is removed to avoid Google Play policies violations.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I was using **device_info_plus 4.0.0** to get Android information.
It is a nice library to get the information from Android.

[pub.dev ->device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/example)

This line will get all information what you want.
deviceData =  _readAndroidBuildData(await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo);

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (dynamic error, dynamic stack) {
    developer.log("Something went wrong!", error: error, stackTrace: stack);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  Map<String, dynamic> _deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    var deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

    try {

        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          deviceData =
              _readAndroidBuildData(await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo);
        }

    } on PlatformException {
      deviceData = <String, dynamic>{
        'Error:': 'Failed to get platform version.'
      };
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _deviceData = deviceData;
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
    print(build.id);
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
      'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
      'version.release': build.version.release,
      'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
      'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
      'version.codename': build.version.codename,
      'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
      'board': build.board,
      'bootloader': build.bootloader,
      'brand': build.brand,
      'device': build.device,
      'display': build.display,
      'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
      'hardware': build.hardware,
      'host': build.host,
      'id': build.id,
      'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
      'model': build.model,
      'product': build.product,
      'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
      'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
      'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
      'tags': build.tags,
      'type': build.type,
      'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
      'androidId': build.androidId,
      'systemFeatures': build.systemFeatures,
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            kIsWeb
                ? 'Web Browser info'
                : Platform.isAndroid
                ? 'Android Device Info'
                : Platform.isIOS
                ? 'iOS Device Info'
                : Platform.isLinux
                ? 'Linux Device Info'
                : Platform.isMacOS
                ? 'MacOS Device Info'
                : Platform.isWindows
                ? 'Windows Device Info'
                : '',
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: _deviceData.keys.map(
                (String property) {
              return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      property,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          '${_deviceData[property]}',
                          maxLines: 10,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Future<String> getDeviceId() async {
  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  late String deviceId;

  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    deviceId = iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor!;
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    deviceId = androidDeviceInfo.androidId!;
  } else {
    deviceId = 'null';
  }
  return deviceId;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work; it returns "Instance of  Future<Object?>."

Comment: I edited the code. that code will return the device id with String format. @DeogratiusMabima

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @ajip  for showing support. I'm using Samsung A226B(reals mobile phone plugged in by using USB wire)  for test and that codes works but still return null on the device id value